# Buying an off-camera flash solution on a tight budget

Tags: off-camera-flash

I am looking for a off camera flash with a wired or wireless solution in a tight budget. My camera does not have a built-in flash wireless communication feature, so I cannot use wireless models.

I capture macro and portrait most.

#### What solution is cheaper?

#### What's pros and cons of each?

- Can I connect speedlight using g a cable to the hot sho?
- Is there a wireless solution to use Canon speedlights?
- which type of wireless communication?

Comment: Hi. While I closed this question as off-topic for the reason of seeking specific products or service recommendations, this question is also unfocused, asking too many questions in one. It's beyond the capabilities of a Question & Answer. This can be broken up into several questions: "Is there a wireless solution to use Canon speedlites?" "What are the pros/cons of the types of wireless flash methods?" "Can I connect...?", etc. Because it already has answers addressing the lowest-cost off-camera flash, please edit this question to focus on low-cost off-camera flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rafael says, forget wired solutions.

So you have basically two solutions to trigger external flashes

- optical control using your camera flash

  - Slave trigger: very cheap ($10) and basic optical control added on the secondary flash (any manual flash will do) that uses a light sensor to detect the fireing of your camera flash and triggers the one attached to it. Can be confused by preliminary flashes from the camera and or sudden light changes. No real way to have auto-exposure, you are working in full manual (but this is OK for studio work)
  - Secondary flash that understands the control protocol emitted by your camera flash (Canon EX series or compatible). This supports the e-TTL exposure of your camera, so you can keep the automatic modes.

  The problem with the optical flash control is that your camera flash will fire, so you will always have some frontal lighting (even of you reduce the camera flash output)
- Radio control. Two categories:

  - "generic" controllers and receivers (you need a receiver per external flash): Cactus, Godox, Yongnuo, Neewer. Not very expensive, but there is no e-TTL support so you are in manual mode.
  - Canon-protocol controller (Canon ST-E3-RT or the somewhat cheaper clones from Yongnuo and possibly Godox (I use the Yongnuo)). You have to use compatible flashes (Canon EX-RT or compatibles)(I use both Canon and Yongnuo flashes) or possibly non-RT flashes using additional receivers. Full e-TTL support.

Using Canon or Canon-compatible controllers and/or flashes is nice, but if you switch to another camera brand you will have to re-invest...

Also, for studio/indoor don't overlook continuous lighting. Between CFL and LED, you can have a very decent amount of light that doesn't melt your subject or your diffusers/softboxs.

Comment: Using continuous light for portrait photography, imho is **very annoying** for the subject. You could have the person frowning and never have the option for an open pupil. Also, I do not know if it changes the behavior of insects in macro photography.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Forget the wire option**. It is ancient, primitive, and prehistorical. Can I give more emphasis to his?

---

2. Probably the two best options are **Yongnuo and Godox**.
3. Pros?

Price, and, IMHO, reliable. I have some Yongnuo manual flashes, for studio photography on location, for some years, and still work fine.

4. Cons?

I think some Yongnuo flash models need a different trigger between them. It is obvious for a manual flash and a TTL one, but I think also on the signal. In any case, think a bit ahead on what your needs are.

5. A cheap option for studio photography?

I would recommend a combination of Speedlight flashes (and rechargeable batteries). I can use them on a big softbox, but as the power is limited, they are close to the subject. You need an "S studio speedlight adapter with Bowens mount".

But also I have some strobe heads with more power that do not use batteries. You can even have a non-radio-triggered one as long as it has an optical slave.

Just see that all have a Bowens mount. It makes life easier.

---

There are two types of radio triggers, a trigger only and the ones that allow you to change the settings on the flashes remotely. I have one trigger only on my camera because it is less bulky, and I have the controller in my bag when I need it, only at the beginning of the shoot.

---

An additional tip. Try to get some softboxes, not the "umbrella-like" that has the strobe head inside. It has a limited range of movements.

A white umbrella solution works on high-key portraits, but you will struggle in low-key situations. So get one or two softboxes.

Comment: In my experience Yongnuo radio triggers, at least the YN622 variety, are very reliable. Also in my experience, Yongnuo flashes work well as long as you never use them. I got tired of them conking out anytime I ever used them for more than 10-12 pops over several hours and moved to Godox several years ago.